# Clamping camera to edge of level java

Tags: java

I am creating a side scroller game in Java. My camera works fine, but I want the camera to clamp to the edge of the level. I got the right side working properly, but what about the left (beginning) side?

---

Code:

**Camera.java**

```
public class Camera {
    private float x, y;

    public Camera(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void tick (GameObject player) {

        if (player.getX() + (Reference.WIDTH / 2 - 8) >    Martian_Run.getMartianRun().getLm().getWidthOfCurrentLevel()) return;

        float targetX = -player.getX() + Reference.WIDTH / 2 + 16;
        float targetY = -player.getY() + Reference.HEIGHT / 2 + 64;
        float x = getX();
        float y = getY();
        setX((int) (x + (targetX - x) * 0.1));
        setY((int) (y + (targetY - y) * 0.1));

    }
}


Martian_Run.getMartianRun().getLm().getWidthOfCurrentLevel()
// Gives the width of the current level
Reference.WIDTH
// Width of the window
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the camera x-pos to `(Reference.WIDTH / 2 - 8)` and add `if (player.getX() + (Reference.WIDTH / 2 - 8) < 0 return;` below the other if statement in `tick()`.

This way the window's left side will never be to the left of the level beginning.